# Получение контента из удалённого файла и вывод его в Toast

Tags: android, файлы

Всем привет, начал заниматься программированием под Android совсем недавно. Вот который день мучаюсь с простейшим кодом. Даже решил попросить увас помощи, ибо сам не в силах осмыслить. Данная программа должна считывать содержание файла в интернете и выводить его в Toast (всплывающее сообщение). Например, в удалённом файле написано "Hello world!" и это сообщение выводится в тоаст при нажатии на кнопку. Перепробывал все возможные варианты кодов. При нажатии на кнопку либо ничего не происходит, либо приложение вылетает. Помогите, очень нужно! Желательно расписать всё подробно, чтобы я смог разобраться =)

Вот полный код main_activity

```
package com.example.byfile;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.example.byfile.R;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     Button btnSend;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);

            btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {

                    try
                    {
                        URL myURL = new URL("http://my-site.ru/file.txt");
                        InputStream dataStream = myURL.openConnection().getInputStream();
                        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(dataStream, "UTF-8");
                        StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
                        int c;
                        while ((c = isr.read()) != -1){
                               data.append((char) c);
                        }

                        String phoneNumber = new String (data.toString());

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
                                toast.show();
                } 
                catch (IOException ie) {
                      ie.printStackTrace();
                }
                }

            });        
        }         
              }
```

Соответственно, в манифесте доступ в интернет открыт.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: это реальная ссылка на файл?
этот код рабочий, если файл доступен извне(проверил на своих).
и, кстати, закрывай stream'ы.

Comment: нет, ссылка выдуманная конечно. но проверялась на рабочем файле на сайте. я пока не знаю, что такое stream'ы =(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        //метод, который получает данные по ссылке
        public static String executeHttpGet(String uri) throws Exception
            {

                String result = "";
                try
                {

                    URL url = new URL(uri);            
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                    String str;
                    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                       result +=str;
                    }
                    in.close();
                }
                catch (MalformedURLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
            }

    //читать данные лучше в фоновом потоке, а по завершению выводить сообщение
     private class ReadInBackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
        {
            String url = "";
            public ReadInBackground(String ur)
            {
                url = ur;
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids)
            {

                //тут все выполняется в фоновом потоке
                return executeHttpGet(url);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String params)
            {
                //тут выполняется после завершения фонового потока в основном
                //так же тут можно делать операции с интерфейсом, если нужно
                Teoast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), params,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            }
        }

//что бы запустить фоновый поток, которые описан выше
//нужно сделать следующее
new ReadInBackground("ваша ссылка").execute();
```

**UPD:**

```
new ReadInBackground("ваша ссылка").execute();
```

это как вызвать какой нибудь метод. Тут создается экземпляр класса ReadInBackground и сразу же вызывается метод execute, который и запускает фоновый поток. ReadInBackground наследуется от AsyncTask, а соответственно в ReadInBackground  доступные все не приватные методы, которым execute и является. Советую почитать примеры от Google.
Если вызов 
***new ReadInBackground("ваша ссылка").execute();***  
сложен, то можно по другому сделать:

```
 //создание объекта и вызов его метода
//а это можете вставлять куда вам нужно будет
    ReadInBackground read = new ReadInBackground("ваша ссылка");
    read.execute();
```

Comment: Спасибо. попытался разобраться, но не вышло...  Вот, к примеру, не смог понять, куда вставлять 

    new ReadInBackground("ваша ссылка").execute();

Не могли бы показать новичку этот полный код активити с "import"? Этот пример пригодится многим начинающим андроидописателям, ибо ни на одном форуме нет достойного примера, только куски кодов, из коих этот код я и собрал =)

Comment: обновил свой ответ, попытался объяснить

Comment: Разобрался вроде... теперь не могу вывести содержание 2х файлов в 1 тоаст. Вот создал новый вопрос http://hashcode.ru/questions/194761/

Answer (score 3):

**Нельзя в главном потоке лезть в тырнеты!**

Вот простейший пример с хорошим описанием [как лезть в тырнеты в другом потоке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example).