# Android: вылетает загрузка файлов из сети

Tags: веб-программирование, android, java

Доброго времени суток. У меня такая проблема, есть метод, который стягивает файл с дропбокса, по прямой публичной ссылке. Но при его вызове, программа вылетает, известно что метод начинает роботу, така как папка создается. Вот код метода

```
// Download dictionary to SD card
protected static void downloadDictionary () throws IOException {
    // Check that SD card is mounted
    if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
        return;
    }

    // Making directory for dictionary
    String downDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + DIR;
    File donwFile = new File(downDir);
    donwFile.mkdir();

    // Downloading dictionary
    try {
        URL url = new URL(FILEURL);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnect.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnect.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnect.connect();

        FileOutputStream fStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(donwFile, DICTIONARY));
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnect.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int lenght = 0;

                while ((lenght = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    fStream.write(buffer, 0, lenght);
                }
            fStream.close(); // Close write stream              
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // MalformedURLException
    }       
}
```

Вызов происходит в onCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if (!DictionaryLoader.getSdFile().exists()){
            // Downloading dictionary in background
            try {
                DictionaryLoader.downloadDictionary();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // IOExeption
            }
```

Но при запуске, вместо того что бы скачать файл, программа просто вылетает с ошибкой.

Comment: Про Debug, LogCat слышали ?  
Permission Internet есть у приложения ?

Comment: Permission есть.
У меня эмулятор стартует очень долго, поетому я сразу тестирую программу на смартфоне. И логи не вижу.

Comment: LogCat и со смартфона логи показывает.

Comment: А если включить отладку usb, то можно построчно и на устройстве выполнять.

Answer (score 2):

ну хотя бы гуглите что ли перед тем как вопрос задавать....

[хотя вообще далеко ходить за примером не надо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/194638/android-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2-toast)

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего ошибка в том, что вы работаете с сетью в главном потоке (UI thread). Выносите эти действия в AsyncTask, или в новый Thread.