# Java Android аналог file_get_contents как в php

Tags: java, android, file-get-contents

Есть ли в Java для андроида что то похожее на  file_get_contents()  как в PHP. Дело в том что я хочу взять код с   html страницы применить специальную кодировку и показывать в WebView

UPD

Благодарю всех кто комментирует. благодаря это я начинаю понимать.

Сделал все по описанию в статье но к сожалению у меня выползает ошибка. При наведении на красные буквы которые выдают ошибку получаю ответ (Cannot resolve symbol 'uri')

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Comment: Тут как бы не все пересели на Андроид с ПХП - наверное надо пояснить что делает эта функция.

Comment: @woesss Эта функция берет с указанного URL весь HTML код. Мне нужно это для того чтоб, запросить код определенного сайта и результат встроить в WebView. Мне нужно именно прочесть весь код с URL ничего больше.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, тебе это поможет. По крайней мере в какую сторону копать поймёшь

```
package application;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;


public class DownloadPage{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fileName = "loaded.txt";
        URL url = new URL("https://www.ya.ru");

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

        System.out.println("Download start!");

        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
        while(in.read(buffer) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer);
        }
        System.out.println("Download finish!");

        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за поддержку. Если я правильно понимаю, то информацию с сайта нужно скачивать порциями и в цикле записывать в файл, а далее прочесть информацию с этого файла. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @AhmadjoniMuhamad, писать в файл необязательно - это просто абстрактный пример того как вообще в java вычитываются и записываются данные. Вот пример вычитывания в строку: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/194644/11515 - только `result` лучше сделать типом `StringBuilder`, впрочем студия сама вам подскажет и поможет это исправить. Так же в конструкторе `InputStreamReader` можно указать кодировку текста - я так понимаю в этом как раз и есть цель затеи.

Comment: @woesss Благодарю за пояснения и за ссылку, то что было нужно. Но к сожалению скопировал и вставил код у меня вышли ошибки в которых не получается разобраться. Поиска в интернете, было сказано очистить и заново ребилд сделать, сделал не помогло и еще не знаю как в этом маленьком поле поставить свой код чтоб вам показать или картинку с ошибками хотя бы((

Comment: @woesss Сделал правку в вопросе можете один раз посмотреть?

Comment: Синтаксическая ошибка - где-то в коде у вас не хватает скобки или наоборот лишняя, или тоже с другими разделителями. Просмотрите внимательнее. На скрине не видно - весь код вообще-то внутри тела класса?